# How do i create a facebook logged in box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Ok facebook's tutorials are all over the place, does anyone know of a place where I can find a tutorial for creating a login box.

I have a login button which i got from the facebook social plugins page, but I don't know how to customize it.

But what i want to know for now is how can i create a login box, when the user clicks the facebook login button, then the button disappears and shows a box with their profile picture name, and my activity.

For example look at WETPAINT.COM and they have what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code provides you a login button. This button behaves as [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) say:

"If the user arrives at your site logged out of Facebook, the button will say Login. When the user clicks it, she will be prompted to enter her Facebook username and password.

If she has not registered for your site, she will be redirected to the URL you specify in the *registration-url* parameter.

If she has already registered for your site, the button will fire an onlogin() Javascript event. When this event is fired you should login the user to your site.

If the user arrives logged into Facebook, but has not registered for your site, the button will say Register and clicking it will take the user to your *registration-url*.

This documentation page is worth taking a look at.

```
<?php

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'YOUR APP ID', 
                  channelUrl : 'YOUR CHANNEL URL', 
                  status     : true, 
                  cookie     : true, 
                  oauth      : true, 
                  xfbml      : true  
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout',    function(response) {
                  window.location.reload();
                });
              };
            </script>

        <fb:login-button
           registration-url="...PATH/TO/THE/PAGE/FOR/REGISTERED/USERS.php" 
           on-login="console.log(arguments)"
        />
</body>
```